# Ember 2 Actions Inside Each Loop

Tags: ember.js, each

Consider the following:

```
days_week: [
    {
        selected '',
        day: 'mon'
    },
    {
        selected '',
        day: 'wed'
    },
    {
        selected '',
        day: 'fri'
    }
]
```

Inside my template, I can loop through the days:

```
{{#each days_week as |day_week index|}}
    {{day_week.day}}
{{/each}}
```

Which produces this:
**mon
wed
fri**

What I now want to do is assign an action, so that upon click it will add a class, and upon clicking again, it will remove the class....

```
{{#each days_week as |day_week index|}}
    <button class="{{day_week.selected}}" {{action 'toggle' day_week}}>
        {{day_week.day}}
    </button>
{{/each}}
```

However, the following code does not seem to work to (start by adding the class *highlight*)?

```
actions: {
    toggle: function(day_week){
        day_week.set('selected','highlight');
    }
}
```

and I get this error: **TypeError: day_week.set is not a function** ?

Comment: typo mistake in your question , selected property is missing semicolon.

Comment: Why would you imagine that a plain old JS object would have a `set` method defined on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ember.set`. It works on any object.

Please check [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/b19b1c0080dcddf20365423473cea8e5) out

Comment: Thank you for supplying a solution.  I tried various forms of this.set() and learned how you can pass in 3 items to set:   Ember.set(day_week,'selected','highlight');  Thanks again!